# Calcular diferencia entre 2 fechas JAVA

Tags: java

He buscado en el navegador y demás y no encuentro la solución que busco por eso lo comento aquí.

**Tengo dos parámetros:**

**Fecha1**-> Es la fecha en la que una persona se da de alta en la empresa.

**Fecha2**-> Es la fecha en la que la persona se da de baja o sale de la empresa.

Pues quiero que calcule la diferencia entre ambos es decir, lo siguiente:

**Fecha1** -> 02/08/2010

**Fecha2** -> 12/10/2020

*Quiero que me saque que la diferencia entre ambos son 10 años.*

Saludos  y gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: @pablo Coger el año y restarlo para que me de el resultado, pero me parece que hay una función por defecto en java que te hace el cálculo y no se cuál es.

Comment: Deberías poner el código de lo que tienes, no sabemos siquiera si estás usando las clases del paquete `java.time.*` (deberías) o las ya anticuadas `java.util.Date` y `Calendar`(intenta no usarlas)

Comment: @Manuee, Si quieres calcular la diferencia de años, tienes que tener en cuenta los años bisiestos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si sólo quieres calcular la diferencia entre los años puedes hacerlo así:

```
public static int calcularDiferenciaYears(Date inicio, Date fin) {
   Calendar a = new Calendar.getInstance();
   a.setTime(inicio);
   Calendar b = new Calendar.getInstance();
   b.setTime(fin);
   int diferencia= b.get(YEAR) - a.get(YEAR);
   return diferencia;
}
```

Comment: Gracias tío, en el proyecto estoy usando GregorianCalendar, lo he adaptado y demás y me va perfecto, gracias.

Comment: De nada, las fechas en Java son muy puñetera :p Tienes que tener cuidado de poner las fechas en orden, si no te va a salir en negativo. Igual es mejor que el retorno lo hagas con el valor absoluto, así siempre saldrá en positivo: return Math.abs(diferencia)